# How to validate the firebase jwt token in my google cloud function?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Users are authenticated in the frontend via

```js
   const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
                                firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider);
```

after that I am calling a cloud function with the firebase callable:

```golang
 const nodeStateCall = functions.httpsCallable('myFunction');
        nodeStateCall().then(...);
```

This workks without any problems and I recieve the jwt token in my go function.

I tried many different variations to authenticate this token. The function which I am using now is `idtoken.Validate()` from the `google.golang.org/api/idtoken` pacakge.

My function:

```golang
func verifyIdToken(idToken string)(tokenInfo *idtoken.Payload, err error) {
    log.Print("running verify Token")
    splitToken :=  strings.Split(idToken, "Bearer ")[1]
    log.Print("split Token:"+splitToken)
    tokenInfo, err = idtoken.Validate(context.Background(),splitToken,"MYAUDIENCE")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("error from tokenInfoCall.Do()")
        log.Print(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Print("Finished verify token.")
    return tokenInfo, nil
}
```

but I keep getting "invalid value" when I send the token.

I also tried the oauth2 service:

```golang
oauth2Service, err := oauth2.NewService(context.Background())
tokenInfoCall := oauth2Service.Tokeninfo()
tokenInfoCall.IdToken(splitToken)
tokenInfo, err := tokenInfoCall.Do()
```

which didn't work either.

What do I have to do to validate the firebase jwt token in my go function?

Comment: I tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176744/how-to-verify-google-id-token and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin#verify_id_tokens but I don't seem to have the right token

Comment: Typically people use the Firebase Admin SDK to validate an Auth ID token. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: @DougStevenson I know, but I can't seem to get it working. The sample for go doesn't show how to extract the idtoken, and When I just strip the token from the bearer It can not be checked...

Comment: @CyrillC, I suppose you are attempting [an implementation of this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) in goLang as there is no Sample in Go, really. Can you elaborate on your attempt to strip the token from the Client and it not being checked? You can provide your code to depict what is being done

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using firebase service, you need to use this to verify your token:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk

Note that you should setup your function in the same project so the library will query correctly.

Comment: Hi, yeah I am trying to do that, the problem is that I do not know how to extract the id-token. or where to extract it from

Comment: The token should be in the header of the request like this `Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN`. Or in case you do `functions.httpsCallable` it already attached to the header. You can try to print out the headers. Look for `Authorization`.

Comment: I did try this but it told me that it wasn't a valid token. even though it was provided by firebase auth in the frontend